# Regex.Split on plus and minus sign

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `1.5(+1.2/-0.5)`. I want to use **Regex** to extract numerical value: `{1.5, 1.2, 0.5}`.

My plan is to split the string with `(`, `+`, `/` and `-`. When I do split with `(` and `/`, it splits OK, but if I also add `+` and `-`, then program crashes.

```
string[] foo = Regex.Split("1.5(+1.5/-0.5)", @"(?=[(/)])");
// OK

string[] foo = Regex.Split("1.5(+1.5/-0.5)", @"(?=[(/+-)])"); 
// Exception catched
```

And the caught exception is:

> System.ArgumentException: parsing "(?=[(/+-)])" - [x-y] range in
>   reverse order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dash is a special character when inside square brackets in a regexp. It means a range: `[a-z]` means any character from `a` to `z`. When you wrote `[(/+-)]`, it would actually mean `(`, or any character from `+` to `)`. The error comes from the fact that in ASCII ordering `)` comes before `+`, so a character range `[+-)]` is invalid.

To fix this, dash must always come first or last when in brackets, or it needs to be backslashed.

And I agree, I'd probably use a global regexp to pick out `[0-9.]+`, and not a split to cut on everything else.

Comment: What do you mean, omits the numerical value?

Comment: it shows (+, /- and ). I think the reverse is what I need. But I have a hard time understanding regex. Currently I use @"(?=[(\/\+\-)])" which splits the string to 6 pieces, which still works. But would be ideal to only extract the numbers

Comment: By "global regexp", I meant using [`Regex.Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) instead of `Regex.Split`.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to escape signs like +?

And why not a RegEx like `/\d+\.?\d+/` ? This won't split it but return the numbers.

Comment: like I said - it's not for split but for match.